# In the following Code , what does the statement SumDif().run(); mean?

Tags: java

what is the meaning of the statement SumDif().run();? 
isn't the synatx for creating an object  CLASSNAME OBJECTNAME = new CLASSNAME();

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SumDif {
   StreamTokenizer in;
   PrintWriter out;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      new SumDif().run();
   }

   private int nextInt() throws IOException {
      in.nextToken();
      return (int)in.nval;
   }

   public void run() throws IOException {
        in = new StreamTokenizer(new BufferedReader(new         
        InputStreamReader(System.in))); // Standard input
        out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)); 
        // Standard           output
          solve();
        out.flush();
      } 

   private void solve() throws IOException {
     out.println(nextInt() + nextInt());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a new object of the class SumDif (by calling the constructor SumDif()) and execute the method run() on that newly created object.

Comment: but in the statement there dosent seem to be any object .all is see is a constructor , isnt the syntax for creating an object          CLASSNAME OBJECTNAME  = new CLASSNAME();     ...........??? is this not the syntax???

Comment: Yeah, if you want to assign that object to a variable. However, you don't have to do that, the object is created anyway. And in your example, it wouldn't be called OBJECTNAME, but VARIABLENAME.